# Is there a way to handle multiple versions of an s3 object as if it were one single object?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, apache-flink

I know there is no way to update an existing s3 object or a file on HDFS filesystem.
However, my data sources are updated with new data on a regular basis.

Currently, I am thinking mainly of JDBC data sources, but later there will be also other type of datasources (ex.: kafka stream).
I am wondering what would be the best solution to store these large amounts of data in the cloud, in a way that allows me to quickly perform operations on it in hadoop.

I would like to execute complex SQL queries on them (for example with Spark SQL), and some kind of ML algorithm will also be performed on the datasets. These processes will be initiated by users in a web interface.

As far as I know, actions can be executed relatively quickly on S3 objects in hadoop.

My plan is to upload only the new data (so what is not yet in the S3 storage) as a new object version in S3. **But I’m not sure I can treat different versions of an object as one single object, and execute sql statements and perform ML stuffs on the whole dataset, not just on the chunks separately.**

I'm a beginner in Cloud technology. Currently, only the data storage part is interesting. If I understand this part a little better, I can plan the rest more easily.

So what do you think? Can I achieve it with S3 storage type? If not, what method would you suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you merely wanting to **append** data? If so, Hadoop will handle it automatically. The table definition can point to a directory and Hadoop will process all files in that directory and sub-directories within it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein So for example I have a db and there is 1M rows. I store it in S3 (data1V1). Next day I have additional 10k rows. So I insert it into S3 as a new version(data1V2). And so on. And I would like to execute complex SQL queries on the WHOLE dataset (data1V1 + data1V2 + ... + data1Vn) as if it were one single table. And I would like to run some ml algorithm on the whole dataset as well. So if I understand correctly... Hadoop will automatically handle this for me if I put these objects in a folder and point to the that folder? In both cases?

Comment: That is correct. Each file should contain _additional data_, and Hadoop will combine all files together and treat them as a single data source. The same for Amazon Athena. This assumes that your V2 file has rows with _new_ data, rather than needing to 'replace' data from a previous file.

Comment: Give the files new and unique names and, the next job will list all files in the dir and process the new stuff. Spark Streaming can poll a filesystem to do this on a dir automatically. Not handled: Schema updates.